# Streaming video from many cameras to RED5 Server

Tags: streaming, red5

I'm wondering what is the best way to stream video from many bnc cameras(already connected to a pc) to Red5 Media Server ?

Thanks fro any tips

Babel

Answer (score 0):

The following code will be helpful for you to stream the camera video to the red5 server.

```
    _camera = Camera.getCamera();
    _camera.setMode(320,240,10000);
    _camera.setQuality(0,85);
    _video = new Video();
    _video.x=0;
    _video.y=0;
    _video.height= _height;
    _video.width = _width;
    _video.attachCamera(_camera);
    uiComp.addChild(_video);

    _stream = new NetStream(_connection);
    _stream.attachCamera(_camera);
    _stream.publish(_streamName,"live");
```

When you run the flash then it will prompt you to select any camera from the list of the cameras connected to your pc.After that you can stream the video live from the camera to the red5 server.

If you want more help, you can ask me.Cheers